# python function not mocked if called from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-mock

I am trying to mock a function when the function is called from a list of functions.

**The below works:**

```py
# demo_module.py

import demo_module_b

def run_me():
    run_me_too()
```

```py
# demo_module_b

def run_me_too():
    pass
```

```py
# test.py

from demo_module import run_me
from demo_module_b import run_me_too

@patch('demo_module_b.run_me_too')
def test_run_me_with_patch(mock_run_me_too):
    run_me()
    assert mock_run_me_too.called # PASSES
```

**The below fails:**

```py
# demo_module.py

import demo_module_b

PROCESS = [
    demo_module_b.run_me_too,
]

def run_me():
    PROCESSES[0]()
```

```py
# demo_module_b

def run_me_too():
    pass
```

```py
# test.py

from demo_module import run_me
from demo_module_b import run_me_too

@patch('demo_module_b.run_me_too')
def test_run_me_with_patch(mock_run_me_too):
    run_me()
    assert mock_run_me_too.called # FAILS
```

Is there a way to get this to work without needing to mock the list to?

### Edit 1

This also fails (And importing directly fails both tests):

```py
# demo_module.py

from demo_module_b import run_me_too

processes = [
    run_me_too,
]


def run_me():
    processes[0]() # FAILS IN TEST
    run_me_too() # ALSO FAILS IN TEST
```

Comment: This is how you should define `PROCESSES`: `PROCESS = [run_me_too]` not `PROCESS = [demo_module_b.run_me_too]`

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it also fails. Edited above

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock before importing the module under test. The code in the module scope will be executed when import the module. It is too late to mock through the decorator when the test case is executed.

E.g.

`demo_module.py`:

```py
import demo_module_b

PROCESSES = [
    demo_module_b.run_me_too,
]


def run_me():
    PROCESSES[0]()
```

`demo_module_b.py`:

```py
def run_me_too():
    pass
```

`test_demo_module.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestDemoModule(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('demo_module_b.run_me_too')
    def test_run_me_with_patch(self, mock_run_me_too):
        from demo_module import run_me
        run_me()
        assert mock_run_me_too.called


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

test result:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
Name                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/61774393/demo_module.py            4      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/61774393/demo_module_b.py          2      1    50%   2
src/stackoverflow/61774393/test_demo_module.py      10      0   100%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                               16      1    94%
```